# NHibernate many-to-many behaviour on db

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, nhibernate-mapping

We have Bar and Foo classes, they have a simple many-to-many relationship:

```
public partial class Bar
{
    public virtual Guid BarId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    public virtual IList<Foo> ManyBarsInManyFoos { get; protected set; } = new Collection<Foo>();
}

public partial class Foo
{
    public virtual Guid FooId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    public virtual IList<Bar> ManyFoosInManyBars { get; protected set; } = new Collection<Bar>();
}
```

At the beginning, I used bag to map this many-to-many:

```
  <class name="Bar" table="Bars" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="BarId" unsaved-value="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <timestamp name="LastChange" />
    <bag name="ManyBarsInManyFoos" table="ManyBarsInManyFoos" cascade="save-update" inverse="false">
      <key column="ManyBarsInManyFoosBarId" />
      <many-to-many column="ManyFoosInManyBarsFooId" class="Many2Many.DomainModel.Foo" />
    </bag>
  </class>

  <class name="Foo" table="Foos" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="FooId" unsaved-value="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <timestamp name="LastChange" />
    <bag name="ManyFoosInManyBars" table="ManyBarsInManyFoos" cascade="save-update" inverse="false">
      <key column="ManyFoosInManyBarsFooId" />
      <many-to-many column="ManyBarsInManyFoosBarId" class="Many2Many.DomainModel.Bar" />
    </bag>
  </class>
```

That works fine, but we discovered that when removing a single association (a single row in ManyBarsInManyFoos table) NHibernate delete all rows related to that BarId and then re-insert the other rows:

```
'UPDATE dbo.Bars SET LastChange = @p0 WHERE BarId = @p1 AND LastChange = @p2',N'@p0 datetime,@p1 uniqueidentifier,@p2 datetime',@p0='2018-05-22 17:22:17.760',@p1='F111C29E-41C1-483F-AC28-053A53713A10',@p2='2018-05-22 17:21:44.410'
'UPDATE dbo.Foos SET LastChange = @p0 WHERE FooId = @p1 AND LastChange = @p2',N'@p0 datetime,@p1 uniqueidentifier,@p2 datetime',@p0='2018-05-22 17:22:17.760',@p1='5204C39B-265F-47F7-AA30-2D104A6FCEFB',@p2='2018-05-22 17:21:44.440'
'DELETE FROM dbo.ManyBarsInManyFoos WHERE ManyBarsInManyFoosBarId = @p0',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier',@p0='F111C29E-41C1-483F-AC28-053A53713A10'
'INSERT INTO dbo.ManyBarsInManyFoos (ManyBarsInManyFoosBarId, ManyFoosInManyBarsFooId) VALUES (@p0, @p1)',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier,@p1 uniqueidentifier',@p0='F111C29E-41C1-483F-AC28-053A53713A10',@p1='D1A635A0-360D-4AC1-98EE-EE3CE47BE63C'
'INSERT INTO dbo.ManyBarsInManyFoos (ManyBarsInManyFoosBarId, ManyFoosInManyBarsFooId) VALUES (@p0, @p1)',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier,@p1 uniqueidentifier',@p0='F111C29E-41C1-483F-AC28-053A53713A10',@p1='58EA2B80-C8D9-4708-90D7-FA110816715B'
'DELETE FROM dbo.ManyBarsInManyFoos WHERE ManyFoosInManyBarsFooId = @p0',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier',@p0='5204C39B-265F-47F7-AA30-2D104A6FCEFB'
'INSERT INTO dbo.ManyBarsInManyFoos (ManyFoosInManyBarsFooId, ManyBarsInManyFoosBarId) VALUES (@p0, @p1)',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier,@p1 uniqueidentifier',@p0='5204C39B-265F-47F7-AA30-2D104A6FCEFB',@p1='B67DE063-BFD9-4AE3-BADA-2B3B5669295D'
'INSERT INTO dbo.ManyBarsInManyFoos (ManyFoosInManyBarsFooId, ManyBarsInManyFoosBarId) VALUES (@p0, @p1)',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier,@p1 uniqueidentifier',@p0='5204C39B-265F-47F7-AA30-2D104A6FCEFB',@p1='0DB243BC-3C89-43E0-AD55-C0CD8120E711'
```

It seems that this behaviour is needed to handle multiple relationships between same objects in the bag, that is not indexed.
But we **need** (due to a trigger or something similar) that existing many-to-many rows in the ManyBarsInManyFoos table are not deleted (except for that really related to the removed relation).

**First question:** Is there a way to avoid this "massive" delete and tell NHibernate to delete only the involved row?

Thinking that probably this is not possibile, I tried to use *list* instead of *bag*:

```
<list name="ManyBarsInManyFoos" table="ManyBarsInManyFoos" cascade="save-update">
  <key column="ManyBarsInManyFoosBarId" />
  <index column="Position"/>
  <many-to-many column="ManyFoosInManyBarsFooId" class="Many2Many.DomainModel.Foo" />
</list>
-------
<list name="ManyFoosInManyBars" table="ManyBarsInManyFoos" cascade="save-update" inverse="true">
  <key column="ManyFoosInManyBarsFooId" />
  <index column="Position"/>
  <many-to-many column="ManyBarsInManyFoosBarId" class="Many2Many.DomainModel.Bar" />
</list>
```

but things become a little bit more strange (for me) on removing an existing association:

```
'UPDATE dbo.Bars SET LastChange = @p0 WHERE BarId = @p1 AND LastChange = @p2',N'@p0 datetime,@p1 uniqueidentifier,@p2 datetime',@p0='2018-05-22 17:56:46.480',@p1='301E92EA-5E37-4948-A0FE-00884D5EB221',@p2='2018-05-22 17:56:32.180'
'DELETE FROM dbo.ManyBarsInManyFoos WHERE ManyBarsInManyFoosBarId = @p0 AND Position = @p1',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier,@p1 int',@p0='301E92EA-5E37-4948-A0FE-00884D5EB221',@p1=2
'UPDATE dbo.ManyBarsInManyFoos SET ManyFoosInManyBarsFooId = @p0 WHERE ManyBarsInManyFoosBarId = @p1 AND Position = @p2',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier,@p1 uniqueidentifier,@p2 int',@p0='CE0C01A3-4F0E-4E93-A33C-22AAE68482D9',@p1='301E92EA-5E37-4948-A0FE-00884D5EB221',@p2=0
'UPDATE dbo.ManyBarsInManyFoos SET ManyFoosInManyBarsFooId = @p0 WHERE ManyBarsInManyFoosBarId = @p1 AND Position = @p2',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier,@p1 uniqueidentifier,@p2 int',@p0='193C5714-FD1C-4C51-AD5F-6B19F262046F',@p1='301E92EA-5E37-4948-A0FE-00884D5EB221',@p2=1
```

Other rows are not deleted but may be "reused" and "switched" behind the scenes from an object to another. Not a valid solution.

Finally, I tried to use *map*... Tried, but I was not able to understand how I can create the right mapping tags for this simple relationship.

Therefore, **second question:** How can I map this many-to-many with *map* tag? And/or how can we map this many-to-many relationship in an optimized way, having NHibernate to simply delete the single involved row in ManyBarsInManyFoos table, instead of deleting many rows to reinsert those after a while or "reassign" relation rows to different objects?

Comment: Use inverse="true" on one (only one) side. Such side should even with bag generate SQL statements you should like

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @RadimKöhler, but I had already tried that and produced the same SQL code (DELETE + n reINSERT). :-(

Comment: Bad... I NEVER use many-to-many.. won't help, I know, but could inspire later ;)